# Why am I getting this error? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I am trying to scrape all of the href attributes from the page below:

Problem is I get the first link but I get an error at that point. Can anyone show me how to fix this please? I am still learning about Python.

Many thanks

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/1'

r = s.get(url)

products = r.html.find('article.contentwrapper section')

for item in products:
  print(item.find('a', first=True).attrs['href'])
```

Comment: `item.find('a', first=True)` is evaluating to `None`. The tag you're looking for can't be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Brian's comment, your code assumes that `item.find('a', first=True`) will successfully find an element. If it doesn't, that code returns `None`, and then you're asking for `None.attrs['href']` (and `None` doesn't have an `attrs` attribute, hence the error message).

If we rewrite your code to actually check the return value of the `find` method:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

url = "https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/1"

r = s.get(url)

products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section")

for item in products:
    res = item.find("a", first=True)
    if res:
        print(res.attrs["href"])
    else:
        print("no match")
```

Then we find that it fails to find any `a` elements in every other loop iteration:

```
https://.../catalogue_product/alassio/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/amare/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/ambient/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/andora/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/antigua/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/aruba/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/avanza/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/barbados/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/bergen-bi-fold-door/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/framed-bi-fold-door/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/semi-frameless-bi-fold-door/?
no match
https://.../catalogue_product/cannes-10mm/?
no match
```

And that's because your expression `article.contentwrapper section` is matching both sections with class `collection-wrapper-item` and sections with class `compare_favorites_section`, the latter of which contain no `a` elements.

If you modify your code to be more selective:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

url = "https://lakesshoweringspaces.com/catalogue-product-filter/page/1"

r = s.get(url)

products = r.html.find("article.contentwrapper section.collection-wrapper-item")

for item in products:
    res = item.find("a", first=True)
    if res:
        print(res.attrs["href"])
    else:
        print("no match")
```

Then you will reliably find the links. Running the above produces:

```
https://.../catalogue_product/alassio/?
https://.../catalogue_product/amare/?
https://.../catalogue_product/ambient/?
https://.../catalogue_product/andora/?
https://.../catalogue_product/antigua/?
https://.../catalogue_product/aruba/?
https://.../catalogue_product/avanza/?
https://.../catalogue_product/barbados/?
https://.../catalogue_product/bergen-bi-fold-door/?
https://.../catalogue_product/framed-bi-fold-door/?
https://.../catalogue_product/semi-frameless-bi-fold-door/?
https://.../catalogue_product/cannes-10mm/?
```

Comment: Following up on this I am trying to paginate it:

Comment: I think this answers the original question. If you agree, please check the checkmark to the left of this question. If you have a new question, please consider opening a new question rather than expanding the scope of this one in the comments. Thanks!